# Jquery: add a css class to specific html element by examining the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I have 4 possible urls ending as shown:

```
   /users/username/bad
   /users/username/average
   /users/username/good
   /users/username/great
```

Is there a way to add a class to an element depending on the ending of the URL when a page loads?

So when `/users/username/bad` loads the element `div#bad` is given the css class `.highlight`. And when `/users/username/good` loads the element `div#good` is given the css class `.highlight`, so on and so forth for all 4 URLs.

If this possible through query? Thank you

Comment: Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/406208/1181310

Answer (score 0):

Just split the url on `/` and take the last element using `slice`

```
$(function(){
   $('div#' + location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)).addClass('highlight'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
var token3 = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3];
$('div#'+token3).addClass('highlight');
```